# find out the character positions from a sring in a data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame:

```
    df = read.table(text="index     Htype
    3 AAAABABBAAAAAABBAAHBUUAUAABBAABA
    4 AAAABABBAAABABBABBAAHBBBBAABAABB
    7 AAAABABBAAAAAABBAAABUBAUAABBAABA
    8 BBBABABAAAAAAAABBABBAUAUAABBAAAA
    9 BBHABABAAAAAAAABBABBABAUAABBAAAA", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to find out the the positions of characters "U" or "H" in the "Htype" column. So the expected result:

```
            index     Htype                      pos
            3 AAAABABBAAAAAABBAAHBUUAUAABBAABA  19 21 22 24
            4 AAAABABBAAABABBABBAAHBBBBAABAABB  21
            7 AAAABABBAAAAAABBAAABUBAUAABBAABA  21 24
            8 BBBABABAAAAAAAABBABBAUAUAABBAAAA  22 24
            9 BBHABABAAAAAAAABBABBABAUAABBAAAA  3 24
```

I used the script not working,

```
df$pos <- apply(df$Htype,1,function(x) unlist(gregexpr(pattern ='U|H',x)))
```

I need helps thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gregexpr` to either create a string column

```
df$pos <- sapply(gregexpr("H|U", df$Htype), toString)
```

or a `list` column

```
df$pos <- sapply(gregexpr("H|U", df$Htype), as.integer)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to paste together the string of positions.  The following works for me.

```
df$pos <- apply(df,1,function(x) paste(unlist(gregexpr(pattern ='U|H',x[2])), collapse = " "))
```